# Filter dataset by 30 day sliding window which has the most rows for each ID using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, runner

I have a dataset with observations over several years for each ID. I want to filter the dataset to choose the 30 day period which has the most rows for each ID.

Example: Format (Date/Month/Year)

```
ID Date
1  01/01/2021
1  05/01/2021
1  08/01/2021
1  07/06/2021
1  08/06/2021
```

Expected Result:

```
ID Date
1  01/01/2021
1  05/01/2021
1  08/01/2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added both `runner` and `dplyr` in tags, the following strategy, will work

```
library(runner)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table) # for rleid() function.  Can work without it also

dat %>% group_by(ID, l = runner(x = Date,
                        idx = Date,
                        k = "30 days",
                        lag = "-29 days",
                        f = length),
           l = Reduce(function(i, j) if(i > j) i else i + l[i+1],
                      seq_len(length(l)-1), l[1], accumulate = TRUE),
           l = rleid(l)) %>%
  mutate(l = n()) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(l == max(l)) %>%
  select(-l)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID Date      
  <int> <date>    
1     1 2021-01-01
2     1 2021-01-05
3     1 2021-01-08
```

dput used

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Date = structure(c(18628, 
18632, 18635, 18785, 18786), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

dat
> dat
  ID       Date
1  1 2021-01-01
2  1 2021-01-05
3  1 2021-01-08
4  1 2021-06-07
5  1 2021-06-08
```

Note it will work without rleid also

```
dat %>% group_by(ID, l = runner(x = Date,
                        idx = Date,
                        k = "30 days",
                        lag = "-29 days",
                        f = length),
           l = Reduce(function(i, j) if(i > j) i else i + l[i+1],
                      seq_len(length(l)-1), l[1], accumulate = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(l = n()) %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(l == max(l)) %>%
  select(-l)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   ID, l [2]
     ID Date           l
  <int> <date>     <int>
1     1 2021-01-01     3
2     1 2021-01-05     3
3     1 2021-01-08     3
4     1 2021-06-07     5
5     1 2021-06-08     5
```